# How to select NumPy matrix rows that contain certain value/values?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have the following NumPy array:

```
m = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [2, 4, 3],
              [1, 2, 1]])
```

I want to have an array that contains the rows of `m` where there is at least one occurence of `1` in any column, so:

```
np.array([[1, 2, 3],
          [1, 2, 1]])
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html) and [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
out = m[(m==1).any(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 1]])
```

Intermediates:

```
(m==1)

array([[ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True]])


(m==1).any(axis=1)

array([ True, False,  True])
```